# Can I pass environment variables to openapi-generator?

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm running `openapi-generator generate -i swagger.yml -g html2 -o swagger-out` and in my `swagger.yml` file I have:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"

info:
  title: "User Web-Service"
  version: "0.1.0"

servers:
  - url: api.myhost.com
    description: "Server"
```

But I want pass the Server URL and Info Version as a parameter variable. Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use environment variables at the moment but you may consider using customized templates (with the `-t` option in the CLI) to achieve what you want.